# What are the the NB-IoT, LTE Cat-M1 and EC-GSM-IoT standards created by 3GPP?

Tags: lpwan, standards

I read an [LPWA (Low Power Wide Area) article](http://www.bing.com/news/apiclick.aspx?ref=BDIGeneric&aid=C98EA5B0842DBB9405BBF071E1DA7651077B1B5B&tid=408BA16913484F6DBD79ECD434C2E3A8&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mobilitytechzone.com%2Flte%2Fnews%2F2016%2F12%2F06%2F8464013.htm&c=8009731986017782477&mkt=en-us) recently that referenced the recent completion of the NB-IoT, LTE Cat-M1 and EC-GSM-IoT standards by [3GPP](http://www.3gpp.org/about-3gpp/about-3gpp).

It seems that this agency specifies the recommended frequency bands in someway, but I don't think that is the extent of it. Is it?

Comment: This seems like a question without enough research. I think we should be careful about this sort of question this early on.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what I should research.  I thought an expert could point me in the correct direction.

Comment: I guess the detail can be found by searching (maybe paywalled, but we can't simply leak that here). Some of your question can surely be answered by wikipedia - its not an expert-level question.

Answer (score 6):

I am answering your title - which does not seem to match your question.

3GPP is a standards body. Back when I was first programming telephone exchanges, the US standards were set by [BellCore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telcordia_Technologies) and the European standards by the [CCCIT](http://www.linktionary.com/c/ccitt.html), which was renamed as the [IT-U](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITU-T).

Those covered ISDN & ISUP, then, later GSM, and GPRS.

Analog(ue) technology was considered to be first generation, and digital (ISN & ISUP) to be second (ISDN was between subscriber and exchange, and ISUP was between exchanges)).

ISCN was still [circuit switched](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_switching), and GPRS, which was [packet switched](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_switching), became known as 2.5 generation, since it used the same [Access Stratum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_stratum) as ISDN.

When a new access stratum, which was much better suited to packet switching, was introduced and the [3GPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_stratum) consortium was established to define world wide standards.

Fast forward to [UMTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UMTS_(telecommunication)), whcih is 4G, and your history lesson is complete.

Like I said, that addresses your question title - the answer(s) to the question body may be different.

And, of course, this is not IoT specific

Comment: Please don't answer titles. A good part of private beta is to determine the scope of the site. Answering ambiguous and unclear questions doesn't help there.

Comment: I edited the title to better reflect the question posed.

Comment: @Helmar +1 I agree! I ought to have posted a comment, asking for clarification. My only feeble excuse it that it's not often that I see questions asking about the last 30+ years of my professional life :-) Obviously, the title - and my answer - are not IoT specific